# Volt iteration comparison with promise

Tags: comparison, iteration, rendering, promise, voltrb

If I'm iterating through an `ArrayModel` using `.each_with_index`, is there a way to make rendering decisions based on the current `index` compared with the results of a `Promise` (at the moment, this comparison returns an error about comparing a `Numeric` with a `Promise`)?

In practice, I have a list that renders ten items by default, and a user can ask to render 20, 30, etc. If I have the user selection change the *query*, then the entire list re-renders, which is slow. If I have their selection change `{{ if index < selected_limit }}` from false to true, then only the newly-showing items re-render. But this only works if comparison of `index` against a `Promise` (`selected_limit`) can be done. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if bindings can take promises, so what you can do is return a new promise that resolves to true or false and the if binding will update once that promises resolves.

```
{{ store.todo.each_with_index do |todo, index| }}
  {{ if todo.selected_limit.then {|limit| index < limit } }}
    ....
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Let me know if that makes since.  Calling .then on the promise will pass in the value as an argument once it resolves, but the result of .then {...} will be a new promise.

Comment: Both phoffer's answer and yours work. Is either a more preferred standard practice?

Comment: use .then, .value might not be there when you check it.  But .then will wait for it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `.value` for the comparison, that's how I did it in a project myself.

```
{{ store.players.each do |player| }}
  {{ unless player == current_player.value }}
    <table class='player'>
      <tr><td>{{ player.name }}</td></tr>
      <tr><td><button e-click='add_vote(player.id)'>+1</button></td></tr>
    </table>
  {{end}}
{{end}}
```